# How to bind data values to Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, google-maps

I am doing some geocoding in my Vue application using the Google Maps API.
In the documentation they show different ways of getting coordinates for addresses.
eg.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Washington&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

But what if I want to use an address that I already store in my application?
Right now I have fields that display street, street number, zip code and city. All these are fetched from my own database.
Is there some way I can bind these to the API?

```
<template>
  <b-form-row v-else class="col-md-12 m-0 p-0">
    <input label="street" v-model="addressInfo.streetName" @input="emitUpdateEvent" icon="fas fa-road"
                  class="col-md-4"/>
    <input label="numberAbbr" v-model="addressInfo.streetNumber" @input="emitUpdateEvent" icon="fas fa-hashtag"
                  class="col-md-2"/>
    <input label="floor" v-model="addressInfo.floor" @input="emitUpdateEvent" icon="fas fa-layer-group"
                  class="col-md-2"/>
    <input label="door" v-model="addressInfo.door" @input="emitUpdateEvent" icon="fas fa-door-closed"
                  class="col-md-2"/>
    <input label="placeName" v-model="addressInfo.placeName" @input="emitUpdateEvent" icon="fas fa-road"
                  class="col-md-4"/>
    <input label="postalCode" v-model="addressInfo.postalCode" @input="updatePostalCode" icon="fas fa-city"
                  class="col-md-2"/>
    <input label="city" v-model="addressInfo.city" @input="emitUpdateEvent" icon="fas fa-city" class="col-md-3"/>
  </b-form-row>
</template>
```

I wish to do something like this :

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?{ addressInfo.streetName + addressInfo.streetNumber + addressInfo.zipCode + addressInfo.postalCode etc. }&key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

I already made a field called "coordinates" where I store the data.

```
  getGeoLocationForUnit() {
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Washington&key=mykey')
      .then(result => {
        this.coordinates = result.data
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like that? I mean to try to add dump address with a comma if this will work then you only should create computed for property map data.

```
axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Washington,Street,Number&key=mykey`)
```

Example:

```
computed: {
 getFullAddress() {
  return this.addressInfo.streetName + ',' + this.addressInfo.streetNumber + ',' + this.addressInfo.zipCode + ',' + this.addressInfo.postalCode;
 }
}
```

Something like that:

```
axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=` + this.getFullAddress + `&key=mykey`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
getGeoLocationForUnit() {
    const address = `${this.addressInfo.streetName} ${this.addressInfo.streetNumber} etc..`;
    axios.get(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=${address}&key=mykey`)
      .then(result => {
        this.coordinates = result.data
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is [template literal strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). String that are wrapped in backticks instead of quotes, simple example:

```js
const name = 'John Smith';

const greeting = `Hello ${name}` // Outputs 'Hello John Smith"
```

For your use case you can even break address info string creation to separate computed property, and that will make

```js
data: () => ({
  baseApiUrl: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?',
}),
computed: {
  addressString() {
    const { streetName, streetNumber, zipCode, postalCode } = this.addressInfo
    return `${streetName} ${streetNumber}, ${zipCode} ${postalCode}`
  }
},
methods: {
  getGeoLocationForUnit() {
    const url = `${baseApiUrl}${addressString}&key=mykey`;
    axios.get(url)
      .then(result => {
        this.coordinates = result.data
      })
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
},
```